# How to obtain $Y$ rotation with only $X$ and $Z$ rotation gates on the Bloch sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, rotation, density-operator, bloch-sphere

Let's say you have a system with which you can perform arbitrary rotations around the $X$ and $Z$ axis. How would you then be able to use these rotations to obtain an arbitrary rotation around the $Y$ axis?

I have seen somewhere that rotation around an arbitrary axis can be achieved by doing three rotations around two fixed axis.
$\hat{R}_\vec{n}(\theta)=R_Z(\gamma)R_X(\beta)R_Z(\alpha)$ for some angles $\gamma, \alpha, \beta$. But how do you actually use this? What if I want to rotate around the Y axis with an angle of $\theta$ , $\hat{R}_Y(\theta)$, then how do I find the values of $\gamma,\alpha,\beta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is in words, more details below.

1. Rotate by $\alpha=-90^\circ$ about $z$ so as to bring your $y$ axis around to point along the $x$ axis.
2. Rotate by desired angle $\beta=\theta$ about $x$.
3. Rotate by $\gamma=90^\circ$ about $z$ to put the $y$ axis back where it was.

The information you need 
for the more general case is on the [Rotation formalisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_%E2%86%94_Euler_axis/angle) Wikipedia page, and on the [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Definition_by_extrinsic_rotations) Wikipedia page.

Your initial specification of the rotation is in the "angle-axis" form (rotating by angle $\theta$ about the axis $(0,1,0)$ in your case). [This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_%E2%86%94_Euler_axis/angle) describes how to convert from that to a $3\times 3$ rotation matrix. In your case
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & 0 & \sin\theta \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then you need to convert the rotation matrix to Euler angles, and I'm guessing you want the $z$-$x$-$z$ [extrinsic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Definition_by_extrinsic_rotations) version in which the axes remain fixed, 
but you should check this carefully. [This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_%E2%86%92_Euler_angles_(z-x-z_extrinsic)) describes how to do that.
There are some caveats in that section about multiple solutions etc, which you should check.
Anyway, in your case
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \text{atan2}(-\sin\theta,0) = -90^\circ \\
\beta &= \arccos(\cos\theta) = \theta
\\
\gamma &= -\text{atan2}(\sin\theta,0) = 90^\circ
\end{align*}

Check also the sign conventions, it's a notorious minefield.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I wasn't expecting there to be so much behind this question. I've followed linear algebra 1 and 2 undergraduate courses but somehow have never encountered Euler angles, which were the missing pieces that answer the question.